# Filter: [?] can not be applied to primitives processing Spring Cloud Contract DSL

Tags: jsonpath, spring-cloud-contract

I have a Spring Cloud Contract DSL that looks like this:

```
    package contracts.someconsumer.messaging

    import org.springframework.cloud.contract.spec.Contract

    Contract.make {
        label 'my_label'
        // input to the contract
        input {
            // the contract will be triggered by a method
            triggeredBy('someMethodThatSendsMessage()')
        }

        // output message of the contract
        outputMessage {
            // destination to which the output message will be sent
            sentTo 'Consumer.contractTest.VirtualTopic.some_destination'

            // the body of the output message
            body([
                id: value(consumer('11111111-2222-3333-4444-555555555555'),producer(regex(uuid()))),
                correlationId: value(producer(regex(uuid()))), 
                service: 'MY_SERVICE',
                payload:  
                [
                    email: 'test@example.com'
                ]
            ])
        }
    }
```

Without the "payload" part everything works great.  With the payload, I encounter this exception:

`com.jayway.jsonpath.InvalidPathException: Filter: [?] can not be applied to primitives. Current context is: {"email":"test@example.com","legalName":"ACME Inc"}
        at com.jayway.jsonpath.internal.path.PredicatePathToken.evaluate(PredicatePathToken.java:66) ~[json-path-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
        at com.jayway.jsonpath.internal.path.PathToken.handleObjectProperty(PathToken.java:81) ~[json-path-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
        at com.jayway.jsonpath.internal.path.PropertyPathToken.evaluate(PropertyPathToken.java:79) ~[json-path-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
        at com.jayway.jsonpath.internal.path.RootPathToken.evaluate(RootPathToken.java:62) ~[json-path-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]`

The relevant line from the generated test:

```
        assertThatJson(parsedJson).field("['payload']").field("['email']").isEqualTo("test@example.com");
```

Just a little more info, this is what the serialized message looks like:

`2017-09-21 08:32:03.721  INFO 10716 --- [           main] c.v.sccdemo.producer.InviteServiceImpl   : Event: {"id":"e63de44e-6e1a-4c4e-b98b-3c49a49efc9c","destination":"VirtualTopic.some_destination","correlationId":"8efb9740-5651-4068-8a6e-574ae7759552","service":"MY_SERVICE","payload":"{\"email\":\"test@example.com\",\"legalName\":\"ACME Inc\"}","timestamp":1505997123576,"version":"v1"}`

Am I doing something wrong in the DSL?  Is the 'payload' part of the body expressed correctly?

Comment: One other note- this is using 1.1.3.RELEASE

Comment: The `payload` looks wrong... Notice that it's considering `payload` as a `String` value instead of a `Map`. Do you think you could share your project somewhere? It seems that the conversion of a message to String is broken but without more information (for example what you are using for messaging - stream / integration / amqp / camel) it will be difficult to help you

Comment: I had a feeling the issue may be the payload itself.  I am not sure that I can change it.  If that is indeed the problem is it possible to customize the way the payload is parsed?  Perhaps by writing a custom ContractVerifierObjectMapper ?

Comment: `ContractVerifierObjectMapper` is a bean that gets injected. You can override it

Comment: You can also just provide your own implementation of `ObjectMapper` and it will also get reflected in the `ContractVerifierObjectMapper`

Comment: Would message headers have any bearing on the conversion?

Comment: I don't think so.

Comment: You're right, the payload isn't correct which is resulting in it being processed as a String.  If you want to phrase that as an answer I'll accept.  Thanks again Marcin.

Comment: Done! Added an answer. Glad that we've managed to sort things out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The payload looks wrong... Notice that it's considering payload as a `String` value instead of a `Map`. I guess it's enough to change the payload to the proper one and things should work again!

Comment: You've been really helpful, it's greatly appreciated.  I demo'd Spring Cloud Contract to my team today and it was well received.

Comment: I'm really happy to hear that! Hopefully the tool will serve you well!